# Cast from float to double produces different results—same code, same compiler, same OS

Tags: c, assembly, x86, visual-c++-6, disassembly

**Edit:** See the end of the question for an update on the answer.

I have spent several weeks tracking down a very odd bug in a piece of software I
maintain. Long story short, there is an old piece of software that is in
distribution, and a new piece of software that needs to match the output of the
old. The two rely (in theory) on a common library.[1] However, I cannot
duplicate the results being generated by the original version of the library,
even though the source for the two versions of the library matches. The actual
code in question is very simple. The original version looked like this (the
"voodoo" commented isn't mine):[2]

```
// float rstr[101] declared and initialized elsewhere as a global

void my_function() {
    // I have elided several declarations not used until later in the function
    double tt, p1, p2, t2;
    char *ptr;

    ptr = NULL;
    p2 = 0.0;
    t2 = 0.0; /* voooooodoooooooooo */

    tt = (double) rstr[20];
    p1 = (double) rstr[8];

    // The code goes on and does lots of other things ...
}
```

The last statement I have included is where different behavior crops up. In the
original program, `rstr[8]` has the value `101325.`, and after casting it to
`double`[3] and assigning it, `p1` has the value `101324.65625`. Similarly, `tt`
ends up with the value `373.149999999996`. I have confirmed these values with
both debug prints and examining the values in the debugger (including checking
the hex values). This is not surprising in any sense, it is as expected with
floating point values.

In a test wrapper around the same version of the library (as well as in any call
to a refactored version of the library), the first assignment (to `tt`)
produces the same results. ***However***, `p1` ends up as `101325.0`, matching the original
value in `rstr[8]`. This difference, while small, sometimes produces substantial
variations in calculations that depend on the value of `p1`.

My test wrapper was simple, and matched the inclusion pattern of the original
exactly, but eliminated all other context:

```
#include "the_header.h"

float rstr[101];
int main() {
    rstr[8] = 101325.;
    rstr[20] = 373.15;

    my_function();
}
```

Out of desperation, I have even gone to the trouble of looking at the
disassembly generated by VC6.

```
4550:   tt = (double) rstr[20];
0042973F   fld         dword ptr [rstr+50h (006390a8)]
00429745   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
4551:   p1 = (double) rstr[8];
00429748   fld         dword ptr [rstr+20h (00639078)]
0042974E   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-14h]
```

The version generated by VC6 for the same library function when called by the
test code wrapper (which matches the version generated by VC6 for my refactored
version of the library):

```
60:       tt = (double) rstr[20];
00408BC8   fld         dword ptr [_rstr+50h (0045bc88)]
00408BCE   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
61:       p1 = (double) rstr[8];
00408BD1   fld         dword ptr [_rstr+20h (0045bc58)]
00408BD7   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-14h]
```

The only difference I can see, besides where in memory the array is stored and
how far along through the program this is occuring, is the leading `_` on the
reference to `rstr` in the second. In general, VC6 uses a leading underscore for
name-mangling with functions, but I cannot find any documentation of it doing
name-mangling with array pointers. Nor can I see why these would produce
different results in any case, unless that name-mangling is involved with
reading the data accessed from the pointers in a different way.

The only other difference I can identify between the two (apart from calling
context) is that the original is an MFC-based Win32 application, while the
latter is a non-MFC console application. The two are otherwise configured the
same way, and they are built with identical compilation flags and against the
same C runtime.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

---

**Edit:** the solution, as [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125754/564181) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127971/564181) very helpfully pointed out, was to examine the binary/hex values and compare them to make sure the things I thought were exactly the same in fact *were* the same. This proved not to be the case—my strong protestations to the contrary notwithstanding.

Here I get to eat some humble pie and admit that while I *thought* I had checked those values, I had in fact checked some other, closely related values—a point I discovered only when I went back to look at the data again. As it turned out, the values being set in `rstr[8]` were *very* slightly different, and so the conversion to double highlighted the very slight differences, and these differences then propagated throughout the program in just the way I noted.

The discrepancy with the initialization I can explain based on the way the two programs work. Specifically, in one case `rstr[8]` is specified based on a user input to a GUI (and is in this case also the product of a conversion calculation), whereas in another, it is read in from a file where it has been stored with some loss of precision. Interestingly, in neither case was it actually *exactly* `101325.0`, even the case in which it was read from a file where it had been stored as `1.01325e5`.

This will teach me to double check my double checking of these sorts of things. Many thanks to [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) and [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) for prompting me to check it again and for the prompt feedback. It was *very* helpful.

---

#### Footnotes

1. In actuality, the original "library" was a header file with all the
   implementations done inline. The header was pulled in via `#include` and the
   functions referenced via `extern` statements. I have fixed this in a
   refactored version of the library that is actually a library, but see the
   rest of the question.
2. Note that the variable names aren't mine, and are terrible. Likewise with the
   use of global variables, which is rampant in this piece of software. I left
   in the `/* voooooodoooooooooo */` comment because it illustrates the…
   unusual… programming practices of my predecessor. I *think* that element is
   present because this was originally translated from Fortran and the developer
   had used it as a means of dealing with some sort of memory bug. The line has
   no effect whatsoever on the actual behavior of the code.
3. I am well aware that there doesn't actually need to be a cast here, but this
   is how the original library worked, and I cannot modify it.

Comment: Note that the literal `373.15` is a double. You assign it to a float. a float is not able to exactly represent `373.15` . However, if the source is the same, what's different ? Different compiler ? compiler setting ? different calls to fesetround(), use of non standard _control_fp() ?

Comment: Correct, which is why I was not surprised by the original behavior of the program, in which the value displayed after casting to double was a long decimal rather than exact.

Comment: "In the original program, rstr[8] has the value 101325." How did you determine `rstr[8]` has this value.

Comment: Note: In general, typical `double` needs 17 decimal digits to uniquely present its value. `101324.65625` shows 11 and 373.149999999996 shows 15.  The degree of precision is not likely the issue here but _may_ help.  Further - I suspect your determination that `rstr[8]` has the value 101325 is due to an integer view of `rstr[8]` with integer truncation and it in fact has the _exact_ value  of 101325 21/32.

Comment: Show me (from both codes) hex value of **rstr[20]** and **tt** value after this assignment **tt = (double) rstr[20]** - same with **rstr[8]** and **p1** var. IMHO - there is sth wrong with your debug method or you are misinterpreting things that you see.

Comment: Is it possible to copy-paste the whole code from the beginning of the function to the line where **p1** is assigned to?

Comment: @Artur, I'll go ahead and pull the actual `hex` values; that's a good idea. The *only* things present that I haven't included are other declarations (no assignments, no statements, nothing).

Comment: @chux, if there is an integer truncation going on, it is in the debugger view. That is certainly possible, but it is reporting it not as `101325` but `101325.`—note the decimal. It may be *inaccurately* reporting it as a whole-valued decimal, and if so that's not the first bug I'll have found in VC6, but it's probably not truncation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

> In the original program, `rstr[8]` has the value 101325., and after casting it to `double[3]` and assigning it, p1 has the value `101324.65625`

implies that the `float` value is not, in fact, exactly 101325.0, so when you convert to `double` you see more of the precision. I would (highly) suspect the method by which you inspect the `float` value, automatic (implicit and silent) rounding when printing is very common with floats. Inspect the *bit pattern* and decode it using the known format of the float on your system, to make sure you're not being tricked.

Comment: Good thought, but no, I've checked that; it is actually exact. More importantly, in any context except the original program (including a refactored version of the program, whether compiled in VC6, GCC, or clang), it ends up assigned to the double `p1` as `101325.` as well—in both VC6 and GCC.

Comment: As noted, I'm going to actually pull the hex values again to confirm that they're the same. The main point of curiosity, from my point of view, is that it behaves differently when compiled with the same compiler.

Comment: I now get to shamefully retract my previous statement. :/ I thought I had checked these as identical, but I was remembering a previous set of related values I had checked. I'll be updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The possibilities are:

1. Despite the reported observations, `rstr[8]` has the value 101324.65625 in the original program immediately before the assignment to `p1`, not the reported 101325.
2. Despite the reported observations, `p1` does not have the value 101324.65625 immediately after the assignment.
3. The program is not performing the assignment (including the conversion to `double`) correctly.

To test 1, **carefully** inspect the value of `rstr[8]` immediately before the assignment. I suggest:

- printing or logging the value to 20 significant digits, and
- printing or logging the bytes that comprise `rstr[8]`, then interpreting the bytes in IEEE-754 64-bit binary format, or
- using a debugger to do both of the above.

Additionally, I suggest testing whether floating-point values are displayed sufficiently well by injecting the value 101324.65625 into `rstr[8]` (by assignment or debugger) and displaying it in the same way as used above.

To test 2, **carefully** inspect the value of `p1` immediately after the assignment. I suggest the above, applied to `p1` instead of `rstr[8]`.

The disassembly code shown in the question would appear to disprove 3. However, I would consider these tests:

- Test whether these instructions are actually executed, perhaps by setting a breakpoint on them in the debugger.
- Examine the instructions in the debugger immediately before they are executed.
- Examine the memory to be loaded, the floating-point register after the load instruction, and the memory after it is stored.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks. As noted in my comment on the original question above, I'll go ahead and pull the bytes and check them.

I should note that the point that is confusing me most is not the original assignment—which doesn't surprise me a bit—but that it behaves differently between two different approaches to the same library.

Comment: Time to eat my words! See update I'm adding above. Thanks for the feedback and the detailed instructions on the best way to look at the data. As it turns out, option 1 was the case here.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho: It’s nice to have a bug involving definitive behavior that can be separated into cases and tested.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do (debugging wise) is get the binary value of rstr[20] and rstr[8] between the old and refactored version. The binary values of tt and p1 wouldn't hurt either. That will prove that the arrays are initialized the same. Assigning a double to a float array and then converting it back to a double is not loss-less.

The only odd case I can think of is the FPU's rounding mode is set differently between the old and refactored program. Check the source code for "_control_fp(", "fesetround(" or "fenv.h".

Comment: Both 101324.65625 and 101325 are exactly representable in `float` (IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point in the implementations the OP is using). There would not be any error or rounding in conversion from `double` to `float` or vice-versa, regardless of the rounding mode.

Answer (score -2):

The first rule of floating point is that results are approximations and should never be assumed to be exact.

Both the compiler and the CPU are able to do plenty of optimisations, and minor differences in optimisations (including lack of optimsations) can lead to minor differences in the resulting "approximations". This includes all sorts of things, like the order that operations are performed (e.g. don't assume that "(x + y) + z" is the same as "x + (y + z)"), if anything is pre-done by the compiler (e.g. constant folding), if something is inlined or not, etc.

For example, (internally) 80x86 uses 80-bit "extended precision" floating point which are more precise than double; so simply storing a result as double and loading it again causes different results to re-using the (higher precision) value already in the FPU's register.

Mostly what I'm saying is that if the exact value you're getting matters so much, then you shouldn't have been using floating point at all (consider "big rationals" or something).

Comment: You need to read the question more carefully. This is a maintenance task; I would not have chosen or advocated this approach (and in fact am not in future development), but it is certainly not possible to simply undo history. :)